# Espresso - Matching an instance of a class

Tags: android, android-testing, hamcrest, android-espresso

I'm currently trying to get Espresso to match a UIElement by it's class and its text since it currently does not have a resource ID (I know, I know...). I'm not sure what the proper syntax for this is since the Espresso documentation is fuzzy (I'm VERY new to this and programming in general so I'm sure I'm missing something). Here's what I have so far:

```
onView(allOf(instanceOf(android.widget.CheckBox)), withText("S"))).
                perform(scrollTo()).
                check(matches(isChecked()));
```

I've tried typing just "Textbox" but in both cases I get an "Expression Expected" error. As of now this is the only way to identify this element so any pointers will help. Thanks!

Comment: Try:  onView(allOf(is(instanceOf(android.widget.CheckBox)), withText("S")))

Comment: I did. Still got the "Expression Expected" message

Answer (score 12):

Here' s my example:

```
onView(allOf(instanceOf(Toolbar.class), withChild(withText(R.string.action_settings))))
.check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

so I guess that in your test would be

```
onView(allOf(instanceOf(android.widget.CheckBox.class)), withText("S"))).
                perform(scrollTo()).
                check(matches(isChecked()));
```

Hope it will help